# Multiway Array Aggregation

Tags: data-mining, aggregation

I'm having trouble understanding how the calculations for multiway array aggregations work using the example used in https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5Ju2x50v6l5X0p3WDEwNkNTVW8/edit at page 165.

Consider a 3-D data array ABC partitioned into 64 chunks with dimensions `40*400*4000`.

It then goes on to say the size of each partition is therefore `10*100*1000`? Where are they getting these numbers from?

Further on it says:

> To avoid bringing a 3-D chunk into memory more than once, the
>   minimum memory requirement for holding all relevant 2-D planes in chunk memory, according to the chunk ordering of 1 to 64, is as follows: 40 × 400 (for the whole
>   AB plane) + 40×1000 (for one row of the AC plane) + 100×1000 (for one chunk
>   of the BC plane) = 16,000+40,000+100,000 = 156,000 memory units.

I understand the calculation for the AB plane but I don't understand the reason why we only need to calculate for one row of the AC plane and then moreover only one chunk for the BC plane.

Comment: i know it is a 4 years old post but if someone can please further explain the question "I understand the calculation for the AB plane but I don't understand the reason why we only need to calculate for one row of the AC plane and then moreover only one chunk for the BC plane." thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is where  40x400x4000 are the dimensions of a 3d cube.

The chunk is 4x4x4 = 64 in this case.  This could be represented by:

**40x400x4000 / 4x4x4  = 10x100x1000**

The latter figures 10x100x1000 reflect the dimensions of each partition or chuck itself.  I'm working on a similiar problem for an assignment I have due in a couple weeks so I Hope I have it right and it helps.